# Traversal description equivalent to cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-traversal

I have a cypher query and I'm trying to write the equivalent traversal description but I'm stuck by the order.

```
start n=node:EduNodes(title='bachelor of science')     
match p=n-[:JOB_CHANGE|EDUCATION|CAREER_ENTRY|EDUCATION_CONTINUED*1..4]->m     
with p, relationships(p) as rels, n, m     
return p,n,m,     
reduce(weight=0, x in rels: weight + x.weight) as totalWeight     
order by totalWeight asc
```

This query is very memory consuming and slow, the traversal description is fast:

```
TraversalDescription td = Traversal.traversal().evaluator(Evaluators.excludeStartPosition())
        .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NONE).depthFirst()
        .evaluator(Evaluators.includingDepths(1, 4))
        .relationships(RelationshipTypes.JOB_CHANGE, Direction.OUTGOING)
        .relationships(RelationshipTypes.EDUCATION, Direction.OUTGOING)
        .relationships(RelationshipTypes.CAREER_ENTRY, Direction.OUTGOING)
        .relationships(RelationshipTypes.EDUCATION_CONTINUED, Direction.OUTGOING);
```

Can I have also the two last lines of the cypher query (reduce order) in the traversal description? I could do it afterwards myself in a loop..

```
Traverser traverser = td.traverse(start);
List<PathWrapper> orderedTraversalResult = new ArrayList<>();
for (Path path : traverser) {
    orderedTraversalResult.add(new PathWrapper(path));
}
Collections.sort(orderedTraversalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your own `PathEvaluator` that is capable of handling a branch state. The best resource on this are the unit tests of Neo4j itself, check out https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/community/kernel/src/test/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/traversal/TestBranchState.java.

Comment: Hmm..? I would have to be able to add the `totalWeight` to the `Path`. From the examples, I can not do that.. But thanks for the link!

Comment: If that doesn't work for you can declare a `Map<Path, Long> weights` and populate it in your custom pathevaluator. When iterating through the results you can fetch the weight of a given path by `weights.get(path)`.